# Does xfs_freeze suffice to snaphot MySQL db?

Tags: ubuntu, snapshot, amazon-ebs

I am writing a script to snapshot EBS volumes on AWS.  One of the volumes contains the data for a mysql database.  I am aware that I need to somehow stop data being written to the database while the snapshot is initiated so that the data is consistent but I cannot obtain a lock on all the tables on the database.

Will using xfs_freeze without a lock on the tables suffice for a consistent solution?

Ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, because mysql might still have data in it's own buffers, that the filesystem couldn't possibly know about.

the proper method is to "flush tables with read lock", THEN create a filesystem snapshot, after which you can immediately release the lock again.

why can't you obtain a lock?

Comment: @r001 I am trying to do all this in PHP ;) and its not very easy to get a lock on all tables in the database.

Comment: @mrwooster Sure it is. In PHP, `mysqli_query("FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK");` then take the snapshot by using `exec()` then `mysqli_query("UNLOCK TABLES");` It's actually very easy.